# Are compactly supported states preserved by adjoints of proper *-homomorphisms?

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, noncommutative-geometry

Given a (non-unital) $C^*$-algebra $A$, I'll call a state $\phi$ on $A$ *compactly supported* if $\phi$ attains its norm on $A$. For example, every pure state is compactly supported (which follows from Kadison's transitivity theorem).

Is it true/known that the adjoint of a proper $*$-homomorphism $f:A \to B$ takes compactly supported states on $B$ to compactly supported states on $A$? Note: a $*$-homomorphism is proper if it sends approximate identities to approximate identities, so that the adjoint at least preserves the set of states.

If it is known, could I please have a reference to proof/counterexample? If unknown, I would really appreciate any references which might lead towards some progress.

Comment: Do you have any more examples of compactly supported states on non-unital $C^*$-algebras?

Comment: Given any non-degenerate *-representation $\pi:A \to B(H)$ and any $a \in A$, pairing with a positive trace 1 operator in $B(H)$ whose range is contained in the spectral projection of $\pi(a)$ corresponding to the circle of radius $||a||$ would be compactly supported (attaining its norm on $a$).


In general, a state is compactly supported if and only if it is contained in a weak-* compact face of the state space (see Alfsen-Schultz, State Spaces of Operator Algebras, chap. 3). So my question is equivalent to "Does the adjoint of a $*$-hom send (weak-$*$ compact) faces to faces?"

Comment: That should be  "Does the adjoint of a proper $∗$-hom send (weak-∗
 compact) faces to faces?"

Comment: Another example is as follows: Given any state $\phi$ and any $a\geq 0$ with $\phi(a)>0$, one can construct via the continuous functional calculus self adjoint elements $f(a), g(a) \geq 0$ with $f(a)g(a) = g(a)$ and $\phi(g(a))>0$ (take $g$ some approximation to the identity on $[0,||a||]$ vanishing near $0$, and $f$ vanishing near $0$ and taking value $1$ on the support of $g$). Then $$\phi'(b) := \phi(g(a)^2)^{-1}\phi(g(a)bg(a))$$ is a compactly supported state (it attains its norm on $f(a)$).